# Can you help me with error fetching data from webAPI

Tags: swift, urlsession

I got this api from https://fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all and i want to get the name to show it to a tableview and show the rest on a detailsviewcontroller. This is all i have done, but i don't know why the data still won't load up. Hope someone can help me, thanks.

viewcontroller

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var fruitTable: UITableView!
    var fruits = [FruitData]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
         view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        
        fetchApi{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        fruitTable.delegate = self
        fruitTable.dataSource = self
    }
    func fetchApi(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data,response,error in
            if error == nil{
                do{
                    self.fruits = try JSONDecoder().decode([FruitData].self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("error")
                }
                
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
here is the error log i got : 

error fetching data!: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "carbohydrates", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"carbohydrates\", intValue: nil) (\"carbohydrates\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: When you set `self.fruits`, you need to reload the tableView: `getData { [weak self] in; print("success get data!"); self?.fruitTable.reloadData() }`

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add that, but it still giving error fetching data

Comment: You mean that `print("error fetching data!")` is printed? Then, replace it with `print("error fetching data!: \(error)")` to have the error thown that could tell you exactly why it's failling. I see the error now that I checked the JSON, but it's important to always read errors, try to understand them (we can help you understand them). So please, do so, and add the error into your question by edit.

Comment: Isn't that the answer to your question? Did you compare the error message with your model types and the json? Check `carbohydrates` in the json and compare spelling etc with what you have in your model.

Comment: the spelling is correct and the type i guess im still right by using double ?

Comment: Well I hadn't looked at the json when I wrote my previous comment I now see that yes the spelling is right but not the structure of your model. `carbohydrates` and some other properties doesn't belong in FruitData, they should be in their own model which is a property in FruitData. Do you see that if you look at your json again?

Comment: is it should be like this ?

struct FruitData: Decodable {
    let genus: String?
    let name: String?
    let family: String?
    let order: String?
    let nutritions:[nutrition]?
}
struct nutrition: Decodable{
    let carbohydrates: Double?
    let protein: Double?
    let fat: Double?
    let calories: Double?
    let sugar: Double?
}

Comment: Pretty close but it seems you have a correct answer below now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You json has some nested data. They should be in separate struct as follows.

```
struct FruitData : Codable{
    let genus, name: String
    let id: Int
    let family, order: String
    let nutritions: Nutritions
}

struct Nutritions : Codable{
    let carbohydrates : Double
    let protein : Double
    let fat : Double
    let calories: Int
    let sugar: Double
}

var fruits : [FruitData] = []
func getData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data,response,error in
        if error == nil{
            do{
                fruits = try JSONDecoder().decode([FruitData].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
    }.resume()
}
```